# Skip object's properties in the loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
$scope.someFilter = {};
```

and later in the code I fill it with properties (for example):

```
$scope.someFilter.Name
$scope.someFilter.Number
$scope.someFilter.Status
$scope.someFilter.Working
$scope.someFilter.Format
$scope.someFilter.Date
$scope.someFilter.Id
$scope.someFilter.Address
```

and so on. What I need, is to check inside an "if statement", if these properties are empty ie. don't have a value, but in such a way that

```
$scope.someFilter.Id
```

and

```
$scope.someFilter.Name
```

shouldn't be checked, because they are mandatory, so they will always have some value. All the other properties should be checked if they have a value, except these two.

I've tried with

```
if(Object.keys($scope.somefilter).length == 0)
```

but it doesn't work, since it get those two properties with a value.

I'm sorry if the question is stupid, I'm new to angularjs and programming in general.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let tempScope = Object.assign({}, $scope.someFilter);
delete tempScope.Name;
delete tempScope.Id;

let areEmptyProps = Object.keys(tempScope).every((prop) => (tempScope[prop] === undefined || tempScope[prop].toString().length === 0))

if (areEmptyProps) {}
```

Comment: I've tried that code, but `areEmptyProps` returns true even when I'm sending `$scope.someFilter.Number` with a value 5 for example. I've also tried `tempScope[prop].length === 0`, but gets true again.

Comment: Corrected solution, try now

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a downvote, but I tried and works now. Thank you!